# What Happened to the previous Mrs Claus when Scott Calvin (Tim Allen) took over the role as Santa?

Tags: movie, magic, magical-theory, santa-claus

Happy holidays, all. Being that it's the Yule-tide season, and we were re-watching old favorite Christmas films, some things got me thinking....

In the 1994 film, **The Santa Clause,** Tim Allen plays toy executive Scott Calvin, who accidentally causes the actual St. Nick to fall off his roof and apparently vanish into the Force or something on Christmas eve night. Scott then has to finish Santa's deliveries to the rest of the world, and in putting on the suit institutes a binding magical contract (hence the titular "clause" pun) where *he* himself now inherits the role, powers, form and responsibilities of Santa Claus.

The film was a success, leading to a sequel, where in Scott, now being Santa for 8 years, *has* to find a wife to fulfill the "Mrs. Clause" to stabilize his powers, or his contract will be broken and he'll run out of magic and thus cease being Santa. This leads him on a mad-dash to fall in love----or at least find *somebody* suitable----- before the next Christmas eve, all while dealing with the drama of maintaining his "civilian identity" as Scott Calvin, including dealing with his now teenage and less than well-behaved son, Charlie, from the first film.

Now *why* they waited **8 years** and *just* before the deadline to do this (beyond plot reasons, of course) is beyond me, but the second film brings up a few good questions:

**1. If all Santas *have* to have a "Mrs," then *why* was there *no* version, or even *mention* of a previous Mrs Claus for the *predecessor* Santa that Scott replaced seen in the first movie?**

Now to be fair, it *is* possible that that previous Santa was still relatively "new" to the position, and hadn't yet come to the 8-year contract expiration date, so maybe he simply didn't have a wife at that time. Given how long "Santa" as a magical Legendary figure role has been around, though---- and the very existence of the "Mrs. Clause" itself--- it is *unlikely* that every (or even *most* predecessor Santas) would just regularly fall off a roof or get replaced within or *before* every 5-8 years. So there *must* have been at least a *few* previous Mrs. Clauses of note, most of which whom would have lived at the North Pole, right?

Well then....

**2. *How* then could the role of Mrs. Claus, an element which could make or break the contract and thus endanger Christmas, be "forgotten" or sidestepped by the ENTIRE Elf populace for *8 years?*** and...

**3. What possibly happens to all the "previous"  Mrs. Clauses when *their* respective Santa husband ceases to *be* Santa?**

Do they just fade away with him, or is there some other explanation?

Granted, I know its highly unlikely the films "canonically" address this information, but I can't help but be curious if this was ever touched on anywhere?

Educated guesses based on the films and any supplementary media would also be appreciated.

Comment: My guess (hence a comment): she just knows, through her own Mrs Claus powers and sadly leaves the North Pole, retiring back to normal life in the normal world. Who would believe her anyway if she said anything? Perhaps she is given a “bereavement” or “retirement” gift where each former Mrs Claus is taken care of until death, by the North Pole.

Comment: Mulched and used as reindeer food.

Comment: @Valorum Dude.... are you okay? :-l

Comment: @MissouriSpartan something like that would make sense; either she kind of "ascends" with him, if they are so intimately tied together, or (depending on how long he _was_ Santa) she is "de-Santafied" and magically given a new civilian identity, with just enough magic to make her normal life easy. Perhaps her memories are erased.She could even move on to serve in some other magical capacity; a gaurdian or worker for Mother Nature or such. I just found it odd that the series **never addressed** such a glaring informational issue.

Comment: @Russhiro it’s a Disney film. Suspension of disbelief required.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan ....Good point.

Answer (score 4):

**There were no previous Mrs. Clauses.  Previous Santas were supernatural beings without families**

In the 2022 sequel series  ["The Santa Clauses"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt17047510/) the whole Santa-Verse is retconned. Per this [recap](https://www.laughingplace.com/w/articles/2022/12/08/tv-recap-the-santa-clauses-chapter-5-across-the-yule-verse/) of the 5th episode:

> Throughout this journey, Scott comes to find out an extensive
> backstory about his reign that many might find shocking. In the first
> film, the slip off the roof wasn’t an accident. **The powers that be
> decided that Scott Calvin should be the first Santa to start off as a
> regular human.** Every Santa throughout history has been chosen to
> properly cope with the issues at the forefront of society. With
> technology coming to the forefront, Scott was chosen to tackle the
> issue. **The hope was that with the addition of Clauses, Scott would be
> able to start a family in the North Pole and, hopefully, raise a long
> line of Santas for years to come.** Long story short: Scott becoming
> Santa was the part of a long con.

In that episode, the previous Santa says:

> The clauses were created to guide you.
>
> The Santa Clause, the Mrs. Clause, all of 'em.
>
> If I'd known at the time, I would've put in the, uh, Less Talking
> Clause.